# Retrieving values from vector at specific index through size of vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

Is there any other way to access or retrieve the data/values that are in vector at a specific index through the size of the **vector**? I am currently looping through the vector starting at a desired index all the way to the size of vector or stopping at

lets say the values in the vector include **1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8**

and I want to retrieve **3 4 5 6 7 8**.

Is there any other way of sufficient way to obtain these values other than looping through the vector?

Comment: what do you want to do with the subrange? Print it? Store in a different container? Please include a [mcve]

Comment: Depends what you mean by "obtain". You can use a pair of `begin() + 2` and `end()` to "have" those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to access and operate on values at index 2 through index 7, (3 4 5 6 7 8)
then looping through the vector to retrieve the values is the most efficient way. If you are trying to group this sub-data and keep a hard copy of your original vector then looping is still most efficient.

**Example 1**

```
std::vector<int> myVec{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

for (int i = 2; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
    // Do your operation on myVec[i]
    // Push myVec[i] to a new list ?
}
```

If you are trying to obtain a new vector from your original vector which contains only the values you are interested in, then there is a better way. Note that the values 1 and 2 are now lost.

**Example 2**

```
myVec.erase (myVec.begin(),myVec.begin() + 2);
//myVec[0] now contains 3
//myVec.size() == 6
```

Putting Examples 1 and 2 together, if you are trying to obtain a new vector with the values at index 2 through index 7, you can use the assignment operator (=) to assign the data from an existing vector to a new one. Note that this is actually not any more efficient than looping through the vector yourself, but might look a little cleaner. After doing this then you can reference Example 2 to edit the new vector to your liking.